# All Mobiles Devices Support SSL?

Tags: mobile, ssl

Would it be safe to assume that all mobile devices support SSL?  I ask because both ScientiaMobile and DeviceAtlas list SSL support as a capability they can test for.  However, this seems somewhat superfluous.  Even the Sony PSP controller's browser (NetFront) supports SSL as does the Kindle Fire (although, in the later case, I believe the Amazon server that the Fire's Silk browser talks to acts as an intermediary that sets up an SSL connection).  In any event, I'm developing a mobile web application and wonder if I need to explicitly detect SSL support in clients that visit my site.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you came up with one that didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, it is depending upon web browser you are using in smartphones. We can't say like all smartphone support SSL. Kindly check for mobile browsers your application will be accessing. You can get more information about SSL supports from their browser website itself !!